# JQueryMobile Can NOT manually submit Form in Internet Explorer 8?

Tags: jquery, forms, internet-explorer, jquery-mobile

all,

I found I can't manually submit a Form in Internet Explorer 8 using JQueryMobile 1.2.

HTML code is below, simple:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" name="test" action="http://www.baidu.com/" data-ajax="false">
  <input type="text" id="id_0" name="id_0" size="20" maxlength="32" value="PLAY"/>
  <input type="text" id="id_1" name="id_1" size="20" maxlength="32" value="PLAY"/>

<input data-theme="b" type="submit" value="OK" id="basicSubmit"/>
</form>  

</body>
</html>
```

I save this page to local disk and Open it in Internet Explorer 8, it will show 2 text and a submit button. But when click "OK" button, nothing happens.

If I remove the line of script tag, which including jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

And jquerymobile style disappeared(it's ok), "OK" button turns clickable to submit. (Though the URL of this form is not correct and IE shows an error message).
I also tried "data-ajax=true" or "data-ajax=false", both failed.

Anyone can help? Much appreciated.

Comment: if `form action` is wrong then it will not go anywhere.

Comment: In fact, I use a correct action in my page, it can submit under Chrome/FireFox, but can NOT in IE. Here the incorrect action is only for sample.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this link](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2628). This issue is fixed in above link only you have to made some changes in CSS which given in that page.

Comment: Thanks. this problem is different with the bug. And the bug should have been fixed in JQueryMobile 1.2.

Comment: I find that I should add <!DOCTYPE HTML> to the head of this HTML file. If add, IE can submit this FORM by clicking submit button. so strange.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the submit button not working in IE9.  I replaced the submit button with

```
<input type="button" id="Signup" value="Signup!" data-role="" onClick="submitForm()">
```

and added the function:

```
    function submitForm() {
    document.registerForm.submit();
    }
```

This fixed my problem.